# My ps4 is making me look up for no reason

Tags: technical-issues, ps4

It just keeps looking up even when the controller is not moving? It happens on all games and i tried resetting the controller but it didn't work. I'm pretty sure its not the controller.

Comment: Lock up perhaps? Please can you add more details to your question

Comment: It's usually a stick drift to do with the controller. You can test by pairing your dualshock with a PC and using [gamepad viewer](https://gamepadviewer.com/) to confirm

Comment: to david yell, basically my controler's analog sticks are not moving but my character still keeps looking up. I dont really know though :/

Comment: To ben, i dont have a pc sadly :/

Answer (score 4):

You're likely experiencing [controller drift](https://www.techradar.com/news/an-angry-gamer-is-suing-microsoft-over-xbox-one-controller-stick-drift-issue). As [Ben](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/users/224988/ben) indicated, if you can get access to a PC this is easy to verify.

Modern controllers, especially those shipped with a console, are not built in a very [durable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planned_obsolescence) fashion. Stick drift is a very common problem with heavy use.

So what can you do? Subsequent steps if a reset does not appear to function:

1. Re-attempt the reset. Make sure you hold the button down for a good half-minute or so before proceeding.
2. Are you still within the warranty period? Is the controller undamaged? Have your controller replaced. If not, proceed further.
3. Try using compressed air to clean the apertures at the base of the stick from outside. Try resetting again and see if you still experience drift.
4. If you have access a screwdriver: Open up the controller and clean the inside. Try again.
5. If you have access to tweezers, watchmaker screwdrivers, a good work surface, and so on: Take apart the controller and physically replace the stick(s). To do this you will need to disassemble the controller (temporarily remove the battery and part of the electronics inside). Sticks are quite cheap, but the necessary equipment may end up costing more than a new controller. You can easily google for instructions. Here's one such [tutorial with pictures](https://www.instructables.com/id/Replacing-Ps4-Thumb-Sticks/).
6. Trash it and buy a new one.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to Hard Reset the controller with a pin. There's a little hole behind the controller. Have a look here for instructions

https://www.lifewire.com/how-to-reset-ps4-controller-4174025#mntl-sc-block_1-0-49